# How to submit form with Multer with optional file submission?

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, express, multer

I'm using multer for submitting form in my express app. The problem is the form has optional image submission option. That means a user can add photo if s/he wants, but s/he can submit the form without image as well. There is no problem with image submission. But multer is not submitting the form when there is no image, even not the other fields.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Company = require('../controller/CompanyController');
const multer  = require('multer');
const path = require('path');

let storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './public/images/logos');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
});

let upload = multer({ storage: storage }).any();

router.route('/companies').post(upload, Company.Create);

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: instead of using `.any()` try using `.fields([{ name: 'avatar', maxCount: 0 }])`. I hope this will resolve your problem

Comment: The problem was at my Controller level. Fixed that manually, multer has nothing to do with it, which I found later. Thnx for the help btw. I used `.array('logo', 1)`, almost same thing but support multiple files, which I'll be in needing later.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One workaround of this is to check the value of `req.file` once your submission goes through. If you do not provide a file in your form, `req.file` should have the value of `undefined`. However, if you submit a file it should be an `object`. Therefore, you could write a simple `if` statement like so:

```
function Create() {
  if (req.file !== undefined) {
  // process image here
  }
  // process all other fields
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Worked like a charm. Though I used `if(req.files[0])`, sinch I'm using the `.array('logo', 1)` method :)

Comment: Took me to figure out what's going on here.  For anybody else, add the words "This is NOT a Multer related issue..." to the top of this answer.